How can I smooth this plot to get cleaner levels?
I'm analyzing some images, and in the course of my project I had to generate plots of the intensity of the green channel along a particular row of an image (as determined by the mouse position). So basically I take the entire row where the mouse pointer is placed and plot how the green channel changes along that row. Here's the relevant parts of the code I wrote -
cv2image = cv2.imread(path)
if 0 <= y < cv2image.shape[0]: #y is the y-position of the mouse pointer
    horizontal_channel = cv2image[y, :, 1] #1 corresponding to green from BGR
    horizontal_pixel_coords = range(cv2image.shape[1])
    ax2.plot(horizontal_pixel_coords, horizontal_channel, color = 'green')

The code itself is working perfectly, but here's the kind of plot I'm getting -

Here's the part at the top zoomed in -

I'm trying to smooth out this plot so that the layers are clear and straight, visible as somewhat straighter lines without so much fluctuation. Is there any way I can process my image or denoise the plot so that I get cleaner graphs?
ETA:
 This is a rough idea of what I would like my graph to look like. (Obviously I want something that can be generalized to create such levels for other similar plots).
Here's the I've used -


“so that the layers are clear and straight” What would that look like? I mean, you’re plotting the data. Are you trying to change the data, or change the plot?

@beaker I'm mostly trying to change the plot - I'd like to take the data and maybe smooth it out to get a plot where similar values are all clustered together and represented as (as much as possible) a straight line. I'm not entirely sure how I can achieve that - I've experimented with some basic filtering and mean/median techniques and they haven't made it much better. I'm kinda new to image processing, so I was wondering what kind of algorithms I could use for this.

what is the goal of this? and what is the goal of that then?

@ChristophRackwitz I've tried out many of the standard methods I could find, such as bilateral filtering, mean and median methods, hard thresholds to cluster the values together, and adaptive thresholds to find the clusters. I haven't got significantly better results using either of them, so I'm looking for any way to get them. See my reply to beaker above for more of an idea of what I'm hoping to achieve.

@ChristophRackwitz I have images where the color in the green channel is supposed to be mapped to a particular thickness value of a material. The images (using microscopes, etc.) I have aren't perfectly uniform in pixel value even when the thickness is supposed to be. So I'm trying to remedy that.

So what do you want the resulting plot to look like? Please post an image, whether it is hand-drawn, created in Paint, or plotted from dummy data.

@beaker I've added it in the edit

show us pictures. I'll give them a look. then we can discuss what's going on and how to handle it.

@ChristophRackwitz I've added the image I used in the last edit

how is that image made? is that actual photography (involving some kind of lens, and counting of photons on an image sensor), or SEM, or STM? is the color false color? I'm asking because the background shows a clear vignette. you plan to use this for measurements, so you should involve some calibration.

Can't you just smooth the plot data? Is it required to change the image also?

@fmw42 I could smooth the plot data, that's what I'm primarily trying to do. But in case changing the image in any way would help, I'm open to that too. I've tried a bunch of methods including some of my own algorithms to cluster, but they either don't help much or they lose too much information.

@AlphaRogue Why can you not take the plot data and apply a running average?

Do you have some assumption about minimum difference between layer? (For example, if you know the green value would change more than 5 at layer boundary... this is edge detection like problem.)

we're having to guess. that's a sign of a question that needs improvement. please explain the purpose of all this, the reasoning behind why you want to "pretty up" (distort) the data in ad hoc ways.

@AlphaRogue as always I would like to ask this question: what if your object looks like a wild banana, would you expect then three "background" regions and 2-4 object - edge of object classes. Generally speaking, unsupervised clustering and then replacing those values by mean or median can be possible

@TinoD Yes, that's mostly what I'm trying to do. If I could find a way to do that kind of clustering without losing too much data about the edges, that would be ideal.

@ChristophRackwitz The reason I would like to clean up the data is that although the thickness is expected to be mostly uniform throughout the region, there are fluctuations in the pixel values which don't accurately reflect that. And about the specifics of the imaging, I will get back to you with more details.

as far as I can tell, the thing's surface curves slightly at the one corner, and the background "curves" severely. either that or your image curves. you need to figure out which it is. that's why I said "calibration". you cannot skip that. if you simply "pretty it up" by not only suppressing noise but enforcing "flatness" where there might not be any flatness, you're working with junk data. whoever relies on you to do a good job will eventually notice this.
